# How to commit changes after I clone a repository which is forked from others?

Tags: git, github

I am new to Git/Github. Here is what I am trying to do (and not able to achieve the goal so far): I am forking from someone else's repository. It is a Emacs configuration. So now my Github page shows this new repository. Then I am cloning it to my local computer, so that my Emacs can read the configurations. I do

```
git clone https://github.com/MY_NAME/My_EMACS_SETUP ~/.emacs.d
```

Now everything is fine and Emacs reads those configs. Then I want to customize Emacs by adding my own configuration. Let's say I modified `~/.emacs.d/init.el`. When I run `git status`, it says `init.el`has been modified. So then I run `git add init.el` and `git commit -m "modified init.el"`, which I though would commit the change into *my repository*.

Then I go to my Github page and refresh it. However, my repository doesn't show the commit I made. Am I missing something? Do I need to run something `git remote add`? Because I guess my commit didn't update any change to Github since it never asked my username and password.

Comment: @Biffen thank you, that's it. I had read `git push` somewhere but I didn't dare to run it because I don't know where it would "push" the change to (intuitively it shouldn't be "pushed" to the original repository that I folked from). I am still not clear about the relation between the folked repository and original one

Comment: Surely you mean "foRked", not "foLked".

Comment: @Jubobs Thanks for the reminder. Didn't think the word through